# Como fazer um merge no SQL quando a variável chave se repete em uma das tabelas?

Tags: sql, merge

Eu tenho um dataset com duas tabelas. Na primeira, tenho informações de trabalhadores e na segunda de firmas. Cada um dos trabalhadores tem um `id` da firma a qual pertence. Gostaria de criar uma nova tabela a partir do merge da base de trabalhadores com a base de firmas, mantendo as informações das duas tabelas. Segue um exemplo mínimo replicável das tabelas:

```sql
CREATE TABLE workers (id INT, name VARCHAR(100), sex VARCHAR(100), age VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO workers (id,name,sex,age)
VALUES (1,"W. White","male",54);
INSERT INTO workers (id,name,sex,age)
VALUES (2,"Hank Schroder","male",51);
INSERT INTO workers (id,name,sex,age)
VALUES (2,"Gus Fring","male",50);
INSERT INTO workers (id,name,sex,age)
VALUES (1,"Skyler","male",44);

CREATE TABLE firms (id INT, name VARCHAR(100), capital INT);
INSERT INTO firms (id,name,capital)
VALUES (1,"Bank Warburg",13051);
INSERT INTO firms (id,name,capital)
VALUES (2,"Atlas Security Information",42094);
```

Eu tentei primeiro usar o operador `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM workers WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM firms);
```

Este comando retorna a estrutura desejada, mas sem os dados das firmas (i.e., nome e capital):

```
1|W. White|male|54
2|Hank Schroder|male|51
2|Gus Fring|male|50
1|Skyler|male|44
```

Também tentei:

```
MERGE firms AS TARGET
USING workers AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.id = SOURCE.id)
```

Que retorna o erro `Error: near line 17: near "MERGE": syntax error`. Como se ele não estivesse reconhecendo a palavra-chave "MERGE".

Como posso fazer um merge mantendo os dados da firma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode haver algumas diferenças dependendo da linguagem de SQL que você está a utilizar, mas isso deve resolver o seu problema::

```sql
create table firms_workers (
    id INT, 
    firm_name VARCHAR(100), 
    capital INT, 
    worker_name VARCHAR(100), 
    sex VARCHAR(100), 
    age VARCHAR(100));

insert into firms_workers (id, firm_name, capital, worker_name, sex, age)
select f.id, f.name, f.capital, w.name, w.sex, w.age
from firms f
inner join workers w on f.id = w.id;
```

O que estou a fazer é juntar as duas tabelas pelo id da coluna, o que dá 4 linhas com os dados que você forneceu. Esses dados são inseridos em uma nova tabela com o nome "firm_workers"

Por favor teste e qualquer dúvida por favor me avise

Comment: Como faço quando tenho várias variáveis? Eu substituí `select f.id, f.name, f.capital, w.name, w.sex, w.age` por `select *`, mas deu o seguinte erro `Error: near line 25: 7 values for 6 columns`

Comment: Ora, a tabela Firms tem 3 colunas e a tabela Workers tem 4. Ao fazer "select *" está a ir buscar essas 7 colunas. A tabela que lhe sugeri apenas tem 6 colunas. Eu interpretei que as colunas id eram iguais e apenas era preciso guardar 1. São mesmo iguais? Além disso, desaconselho fazer select * porque depois é mais difícil perceber o que a query está a fazer